# Probability. (Prove/Disprove)

Tags: probability

The question says: Prove or disprove - $P(A)=P(\bar{B})$ => $\bar{A}=B$.

Assuming that we are talking of the same sample space(otherwise, its obvious), my take on the problem goes as follows:

[image]

I am considering two situations, $P(A\cap B)=0$ and $P(A\cap B)\neq 0$.

Consider the RHS of the line, given, $P(A)=P(\bar{B})$, i.e. the shaded regions must be the same, that's only possible when $P(A\cap B)=0$ and $P(A\cup B)=1$ and hence situation should be like the image on LHS, which implies $\bar{A}=B$. { Taking the left circle as event $A$ and the right one as $B$, and the rectangle is the sample space. }

Is that right ?

Answer (score 2):

From $P(A)=P(B^{\complement})$ you cannot deduce that the shaded regions *are the same* but only that *the shaded regions have the same probability*.

E.g. think of set $\{1,2,3\}$ with $P(\{1\})=0.5=P(\{3\})$ and (consequently) $P(\{2\})=0$.

Then $P(\{1\})=0.5=P(\{3\}^{\complement})$ but $\{1\}^{\complement}=\{2,3\}\neq\{3\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Omega=\{a,b,c,d\} $, $A$={a,b},$\overline A=\{c,d\}$ $B=\{a,d\}$, $\overline B=\{b,c\}$. If all the elementary events are of the same probability then $P(A)=P(\overline B)=\frac12.$ But $\overline A\not =B.$ Although, $P(\overline A)=P(B).$